# How to trigger checkbox click and extract corresponding value?

Tags: angular

I have pairs of [value, checkbox] with the following structure

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
  <td>{{ element.id }}</td>

  <td>
    <label class='checkbox'>
      <input type='checkbox'>
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How do I catch a click on checkbox and then capture corresponding value so I can send it to server as s parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just listen for the event and invoke a callback function when it occurs.

```
<label class='checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' (click)="send($event.currentTarget.checked)"> Click Me!
</label>
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fX2TwniDAx46hZXid9uY)

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass your array iteration value using function to the server like this.

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
  <td>{{ element.id }}</td>

  <td>
    <label class='checkbox'>
      <input type='checkbox' (click)='getValue(element)'>
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>

function getValue(value){
   console.log(value);
}
```